# I'm struggling with Bash regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm frustrated trying to find out how to use regex to do anything useful. I'm completely uncertain on everything that I do, and I've resorted to trial and error; which has not been effective.

I'm trying to list files in the current directory that starts with a letter, contains a number, end with a dot followed by a lowercase character, etc. 
So I know starts with a letter would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z]
```

but I don't know how to follow that up with CONTAINS a number. I know ends with a dot can be `[\.]*`, but I'm not sure. I'm seeing that `$` is also used to match strings at the end of the word.

I have no idea if I should be using `find` with regex to do this, or `ls | grep` .... I'm completely lost. Any direction would be appreciated.

I guess the specific question I was trying to ask, was how to I glue the expressions together. For example, I tried ls | grep ^[a-zA-Z][0-9] but this only shows files that start with letter, followed by a number. I don't know how write a regex that starts with a letter, and then add the next requirement, ie. contains a number.

Comment: I find it hard to see a specific question here. General pointers to good reads for Bash pattern matching and regular expressions are [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) and the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern). If you want to learn about `find`, the [findutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) is the place to go.

Comment: Regexes you use with `grep` aren't **bash** regular expressions, they're **grep** regular expressions -- which may be BREs, EREs, or even PCREs depending on your grep version and which options you pass. **bash** regular expressions are used with `[[ $str =~ $re ]]` syntax, and purely conform with ERE syntax.

Comment: Most importantly experiment with Regex - test regex against strings - use sites like regexr, regex101

Comment: Sounds like you want simply a glob pattern, not a regex.  `for file in [A-Za-z]*[0-9]*[A-Za-z]; do ... something with "$file"; done`

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of documentation online, eg. [GNU's Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

Your particular example, would require something like:

```
^[:alpha:].*[:digit:].*\.[:lower:]$
```

or if POSIX classes are not available:

```
^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]$
```

You can read either as:

- start of line
- a letter (upper or lower case)
- any character, zero or more times
- a digit
- any character, zero or more times
- a dot (must be escaped with a backslash)
- a lower case letter
- end of line

Once you settle on a regular expression, you can use it with `ls` within the directory you wish to find the files in:

```
cd <dir>
ls -1 | grep '^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]$'
```

NOTE: I tried to improve my answer based on some of the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: This answer conflates several unrelated things. For instance, `ls [a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]` isn't using a regular expression at all, it's using a glob pattern (which is why `.*` didn't do what you intended). Moreover, whether POSIX classes are available in is entirely well-defined (in they're available in all three of globs, BRE and ERE).

Comment: Moreover, the ABS is an **exceedingly** poor reference -- often out-of-date, and consistently using bad practices in its examples; much of what we do in the freenode #bash channel is try to break people of unfortunate habits they picked up using it (in the words of [the factoid](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs), "the ABS will teach you to write bugs, not scripts"). The [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) are sources of far better repute.

Comment: ...the bash-hackers page on globbing is [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs), the page on pattern-matching in general is [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern), and native regex matching with `=~` is covered in [the page on conditionals](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), which links to [the Wikipedia page on POSIX ERE, the relevant regex syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended).

Answer (score 0):

- Starts with a letter: `^[a-zA-Z]`
- Contains a number: `.*[0-9].*`
- Ends with a dot and lowercase letter: `\.[a-z]$`

Together:

```
^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]$
```

The best way to find files that match a regex is with `find -regex`. When you use that the `^` and `$` anchors are implied, so you can omit them. You'll need to tack on `.*/` at the front to match any directory, since `-regex` matches both the directory and file name.

```
find -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]'
```